# Java: Scope of a variable in a loop and performance

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I use Oracle JDK8. Let's say we have following two classes:

```
class MyLoop {

    private final long times;

    MyLoop(final long times) {
        this.times = times;
    }

    int widerScope() {
        final String var = MyClass.VARIABLE;

        int j = 0;
        for (long l = 0; l < times; l++) {
            j += var.length();
        }

        return j;
    }

    int narrowerScope() {
        int j = 0;
        for (long l = 0; l < times; l++) {
            final String var = MyClass.VARIABLE;

            j += var.length();
        }

        return j;
    }

}

class MyClass {
    static final String VARIABLE = "foo";
}
```

I'd like to know which one is more efficient, `widerScope()` and `narrowerScope()`. I prefer `narrowerScope()` because the scope of the variable `var` is narrower, but `widerScope()` initializes the variable `var` only once, so it may be more efficient, I guess.

I also created a testcase for benchmarking, but I couldn't see any significant difference of execution times.

```
public class MyLoopTest {

    private final MyLoop sut = new MyLoop(6000000000L);

    @Test
    public void narrower() throws Exception {
        sut.narrowerScope();
    }

    @Test
    public void wider() throws Exception {
        sut.widerScope();
    }
}
```

What do you think? Or, Are there any references, specification or information to make this question clear?

Comment: If `MyClass.VARIABLE` is a constant, there's not likely to be any difference, especially once the JIT compiler kicks in. Better spend your time trying to write clean, readable code.

Comment: @shmosel: Since `MyClass.VARIABLE` *is* a constant, `var` will be a constant too. So in both variants, the statement, `j += var.length()` will produce identical code, exactly as if `j += "foo".length()` had been written. When you compile without enabling debug information, i.e. without retaining unused variables, the entire code of both methods will be identical (the variable numbering may differ). When the JIT compiler kicks in, it doesn’t even matter whether `VARIABLE` is a constant. As long as it hasn’t been declared `volatile`, it may be treated like constant during the entire loop.